# Weights argument in R gbm function

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, data-mining, gbm

What is the `weights` argument for in the R [gbm](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/gbm/docs/gbm) function? Does it implement **cost-sensitive** stochastic gradient boosting?

Answer (score 4):

You may have already read this, but the documentation says that the `weights` parameter is defined in this way:

> an optional vector of weights to be used in the fitting process. Must
>   be positive but do not need to be normalized. If keep.data=FALSE in
>   the initial call to gbm then it is the user’s responsibility to
>   resupply the weights to gbm.more.

Thus my interpretation would be that they are standard observation weights as in any statistical model.

Is it cost-sensitive? Good question. I first noticed that one of the main citations for the package is:

*B. Kriegler (2007). [Cost-Sensitive Stochastic Gradient Boosting Within a Quantitative Regression Framework](http://statistics.ucla.edu/theses/uclastat-dissertation-2007:2).*

so I figured it does imply cost-sensitivity, but there's not an explicit use of that term in the vignette, so if it was not apparent.

I did a little bit of a deeper dive though and found some more resources. You can find the equations describing the weights towards the end of [this](https://gradientboostedmodels.googlecode.com/git/gbm/inst/doc/gbm.pdf) article which describes the package.

I also found this question being asked [way back in 2009 in a mailing list](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/gbm-for-cost-sensitive-binary-classification-td896517.html), and while there was no response, I finally found a a [scholarly article](http://statistics.ucla.edu/system/resources/BAhbBlsHOgZmSSIBizIwMTIvMDUvMTcvMTRfMzNfMzdfOTYyX0VzdGltYXRpbmdfdGhlX0hvbWVsZXNzX1BvcHVsYXRpb25faW5fTG9zX0FuZ2VsZXNfQW5fQXBwbGljYXRpb25fb2ZfQ29zdF9TZW5zaXRpdmVfU3RvY2hhc3RpY19HcmFkaWVudF9Cb29zdGluZy5wZGYGOgZFVA/Estimating%20the%20Homeless%20Population%20in%20Los%20Angeles:%20An%20Application%20of%20Cost-Sensitive%20Stochastic%20Gradient%20Boosting.pdf) discussing the use of `gbm` and other R packages for cost-sensitive gradient boosting.

The conclusion is that `gbm`'s quantile loss function is differentiable and can be used in cost-sensitive applications wherein over/under-estimation have different error costs, however other quantitative loss functions (aside from quantile) may be necessary/appropriate in some applications of cost-sensitive gradient boosting.

That paper is centered around `gbm` but also discusses other packages and if your focus is on cost-sensitive gradient boosting then you may want to look at the others they mention in the paper as well.